# Deploy meanjs based application hosted in Github to Bluemix

Tags: github, ibm-cloud, meanjs, devops

My application using meanjs framework is hosted in Github repository. How do I integrate Bluemix and Git to deploy my application to Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option for using Git to deploy to Bluemix from a Github repository is to use this link:

https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=LINK-TO-YOUR-GITHUB-REPO

This will grab your repository, launch a Bluemix application with it and create a Bluemix DevOps project that allows you to push changes to your application with Git instead of the [Cloud Foundry CLI tool](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/install_cli.html).

You can also manually perform this process by starting here (https://hub.jazz.net/create). On this setup page, be sure to select 'Make this a Bluemix Project' so you can deploy your code to Bluemix.

**FYI** - Just deploying a repository to Bluemix does not mean that it will run on the platform. See [here for more info](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html) on getting your code to work on Bluemix.

Answer (score -1):

1. Deploy the project into Bluemix as below:

   - download meanjs from Github at: https://github.com/meanjs/mean
   - install dependency packages by `npm -install`
   - check and see if the project can run at local by command `grunt` as meansjs project describes
   - create a mongolab service in Bluemix with named `mean-mongo`
   - check .cfignore file contains below items;
   - List of files and directories to ignore when deploying to Bluemix (`.DS_Store`, `.nodemonignore`, `.sass-cache/`, `npm-debug.log`, `node_modules/`, `public/lib`, `app/tests/coverage/`, `.bower-*/`, `.idea/`)

     - push the application by `cf push <appname> -p` .
2. Integrate the app to Git

   - make sure that step 1 completes successfully, and the application is upload to Bluemix successfully
   - add the app deployed to Bluemix in step 1 to jazz hub by (click the app -> click "ADD GIT" at upper right of the app - > then it will create url to the jazz hub project
   - login onto jazz hub by clicking "GIT URL" or "EDIT" button at the app page
   - it will open jazz hub page

     3. further reference
   - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-intro1-app/